# on enter, prevent whole form validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have a view which contains a partial view (like a login widget at the top left, when clicked upon, it expands and you enter your username/password followed by a submit button) and also the main body contains an input field but you need to click on one of the 2 links there to continue.

that field contains form validation (Required attribute on the textbox)

When the user hits enter on the keyboard when they expand the login widget, I want it invoke the submit button but currently this causes the form validation to kick in thus saying the input box on the main form needs to be entered.

how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

isn't that the point of validating input fields? preventing users from submitting wrong things?

but if you want to do this, you could listen to the keypress in javascript and remove the required attributes from the input fields.

Comment: Probably would not work, If it is Mvc there is server side validation to. If I understand the question he just needs to prevent enter from posting the form, which can be done easily. Posting without server side validation requires removing said server side validation.

Comment: Right. so basically what I am saying is, when they hit enter on the widget, I want to do a submit on that. Problem is, the main form gets validated and thinks it is the one being submitted when really, it is not.